# Cannot charge laptop battery

Tags: laptop, battery, charger, ac-adapter

My laptop had gotten pretty old and the battery would not charge so I bought a new battery. I soon noticed that the new battery would not charge either. When I plug the cable in it charges for a few seconds and says "plugged in, not charging" in the system tray. If I take the cord out then plug it back in it works fine... For about 10 seconds, then say not charging again. I finally thought it was the ac/dc power cord, so i bought a new one. The first time I plugged it in it had a slightly different result. It started charging then said "28 minutes to full charge" but after a little bit it said "plugged in, not charging". After unplugging and replugging it does the same thing as before.
 I should note that running the laptop without the battery (only the cord) works fine.

thanks for all your help

Dennis

Comment: Can you charge it with the power off? Turn off the power, remove the battery, and press and hold the power key for about 30 seconds. Then reconnect the battery and plug in the cord, but do not turn on the laptop. After several seconds, does the charge light come one and stay on?

Comment: What is the charge level in the battery?

Comment: @acejavelin I tried what you said but I don't have a charge light (dell insprion 15) so I can't see if its charging. But after waiting 20 min and starting it up it is still at 87%.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The battery is at 87% but slips lower if I unplug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the laptop's power manager is deciding that charging past 87% will be harmful to the battery's life. It also may be that the new battery is not calibrated yet and so it really is 100% charged even though it's only displaying 87%.

You aren't reporting any actual problem (such as poor battery life) so your issues seem to be purely cosmetic. Use the battery through a full cycle or two and you'll probably find there's no problem at all.

Comment: Bravo! I drained the battery and am charging it back up again. Not sure if it will go to 100% but I guess i'll see. Thanks again.